# Como recarregar uma tabela em HTML e seus dados após o clique de um botão usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos

Estou fazendo um formulário em HTML e em certo momento adiciono algumas informações e passo para um Array em javascript através de uma função onclick em um botão e após isso gostaria que as informações que estão nesse Array fossem recarregadas a cada clique na seguinte tabela:

```
<div class="form-row" id="tabelaCursos" style="display: none;">

            <div class="col-md-8 mb-3">
                <table class="table table-sm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Curso</th>
                            <th scope="col">Duração</th>
                            <th scope="col">Instituição</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <script>
                        for (var i = 0; i < listaCursos.length; i++) {
                            var item = listaCursos[i];
                            alert("Entrou"+item.Nome)
                            document.write("<tr><td>"+item.Nome+"</td><td>"+item.Duracao+"</td><td>"+item.Instituicao+"</td></tr>")
                        </script>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
</div>
```

Estou usando um for para poder pegar os dados desse array, entretanto ele precisa ser recarregado a cada novo curso adicionado nesse Array, como posso fazer isso?

Código da função do onclick no botão:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-top: 31px;"
                    onclick="cadastrarCurso()">Adicionar</button>

function cadastrarCurso() {
                    document.getElementById("tabelaCursos").style.display = 'block';
                    var nome = (document.getElementById("curso").value);
                    var duracao = (document.getElementById("duracao").value);
                    var instituicao = (document.getElementById("instituicao").value);

                    var curso = new Curso();
                    curso.SetNome(nome);
                    curso.SetDuracao(duracao);
                    curso.SetInstituicao(instituicao)

                    addLista(curso)

                }

function addLista(curso) {
listaCursos = [curso]
}
```

Comment: Vc pode criar uma função que exiba essa tabela, ao invés de deixar ela pronta no HTML, assim que o evento onclick disparar vc chama essa função e passa o array com os dados como parâmetro. É assim que eu costumo fazer.

Comment: _"através de uma função onclick em um botão"_ ... podes mostrar essa função? Essa função vai alterar a `listaCursos`?

Comment: @GabrielFernandes, mas ai eu usaria um document.write nessa função?

Comment: @Sergio adicionei a função chamada no onclick

Comment: Não deveria ser `listaCursos = listaCursos.concat(curso);` ou `listaCursos.push(curso)` em vez de `listaCursos = [curso]`?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo @Sergio foi um erro, já atualizei

Answer (score 0):

A Solução encontrada para o problema foi fazer uma chamada a outra função no clique do botão:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="margin-top: 31px;"
                    onclick="cadastrarCurso();exibirDadosTabela()">Adicionar</button>
```

Foi utilizado o innerHTML na função exibirDadosTabela() para poder criar o codigo das colunas com seus dados:

```
function exibirDadosTabela(){
                                var stringAux = ""
                                for (var i = 1; i < listaCursos.length; i++) {
                                    var item = listaCursos[i];
                                    stringAux += "<tr><td>"+item.Nome+"</td><td>"+item.Duracao+"</td><td>"+item.Instituicao+"</td></tr>";
                                }
                                document.getElementById("corpoTabela").innerHTML = stringAux
                            }
```

Também foi alterado o código da função addLista() para:

```
function addLista(curso) {
                    listaCursos.push(curso)
                }
```